# Has destruction in Gaza thus far (Dec 11 or so) been greater than in German cities during WW2?

Tags: world-war-ii, israel-hamas-war

*The Times of Israel* [quotes](https://www.timesofisrael.com/top-eu-diplomat-gaza-destruction-proportionally-even-greater-than-in-wwii-germany/#:%7E:text=The%20situation%20in%20Gaza%20is,%2C%20Josep%20Borrell%2C%20said%20Monday.) on Dec 11:

> The situation in Gaza is “catastrophic, apocalyptic,” with destruction proportionally “even greater” than that which Germany experienced in World War II, the EU’s top diplomat, Josep Borrell, said Monday.

Borrell might have actually said that or something very similar a few days earlier. Anadolu [reported](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/europe/destruction-in-gaza-comparable-if-not-higher-to-wwii-germany-says-eu-foreign-policy-chief/3077510) on Dec 8:

> Talking to Spanish state broadcaster RTVE, Josep Borrell said the bombing campaign in the Palestinian enclave was already "one of the most intense in history" and denounced the level of destruction of its cities as "comparable, if not higher, to levels of destruction of German cities during the Second World War."

Is this true? Has destruction in Gaza been "even greater" than that of German cities in WW2?

(I'm assuming destruction can be objectively quantified to a good extent, although one would have to be wary that the same standards/methods are used for comparison. See e.g. [related Q](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/55986/were-90-of-mariupols-apartment-buildings-destroyed-during-2022-battles) here.)

Comment: You'll need to narrow the focus and decide on an objective criteria.

Comment: Perhaps the criteria there should be the more quantifiable tonnage of ordnance. But there is the word **proportionally** which clouds the issue. Proportional to what? Land area, population, *anger*? Considering that Gaza is (or was) densely populated, that's a difficult comparison – and *which* German cities?

Comment: This might help: In 1953, the USAF commissioned a report on the ordnance dropped on the seven largest German cities: https://web.archive.org/web/20130218171142/http://www.afhso.af.mil/shared/media/document/AFD-110208-030.pdf. The tonnage per 100000 capita ranges from ~1000 (Dresden) to almost 6000 (Cologne). This would mean between 6500t and 34000t of bombs on Gaza City, for example. Getting reliable numbers will probably take years.

Comment: @JörgWMittag that is cherry picking. How you define a "German city" is paramount. The quote seems like a "sound bite" or a "throwaway comment", not an actual verifiable statistic.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm not sure tonnage of bombs is the best measure of the "amount of destruction"

Comment: @TimRias how do you even measure "amount of destruction"? By the cost to rebuild? By the number of humans killed?

Comment: @WeatherVane That is a good question

Comment: Reminder: The OP isn't the one who gets to define the terms. We either need to figure out what the claimant meant, or failing that, include the definitions we use in the answers.

Comment: @WeatherVane Dropping 6,000t of bombs over L.A. is not going to produce anywhere the same results as over Brooklyn alone, or any 5,000 people little town in Nebraska. Bombs per acre would be more meaningful, probably. Or percentage of buildings destroyed. Percentage of people affected/injured. What is clear is that absolute numbers are meaningles.

Comment: Tonnage of bombs is probably not a good measure - in WW2 heavy use of incendiaries on buildings using wood in their construction had a big impact on the level of destruction.  And in Gaza, the IDF is using bulldozers to destroy housing, which is nothing to do with tonnage of bombs.  The BBC commissioned a [survey](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-67565872) back at the end of November which shows some areas completely cleared by bulldozers.

Comment: Percentage of homes damaged or destroyed is probably a decent metric - the UN Office for the Coordination of Humanitarian Affairs [have that](https://www.unocha.org/publications/report/occupied-palestinian-territory/hostilities-gaza-strip-and-israel-flash-update-53) at 60% and 10% as of 29th Nov. Since this was widely reported at the beginning of December, it may well be the figures Borrell was using. But I don't know where to find comparable numbers for WW2.

Comment: Wikipedia [has](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombing_of_Berlin_in_World_War_II) Berlin at the end of the war with "Half of all houses were damaged and around a third uninhabitable". We don't have percent completely destroyed for Berlin or percent uninhabitable for Gaza, but percent damaged figures are similar. But we don't know if the same definition of damaged was used.

Comment: The statement may well be true, it's not necessarily fair to take the average for the whole of Germany (which included many rural areas that would not have been subject to intense fighting) and comparing it with a single city that is being fought over street by street.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As there are many ways to define destruction, let's narrow it down to
mean damage to buildings (we exclude damage to infrastructure,
farmland, movable property, etc). Moreover, let's measure amount of
destruction as number of buildings destroyed because trying to weigh
for property values would be a fool's errand. This map illustrates how
["how badly German cities were hit by Allied bombing raids"](https://bigthink.com/strange-maps/air-war-germany-map/) during
World War II:

[image]

The [same source](https://bigthink.com/strange-maps/air-war-germany-map/) claims that 9.4% of the East German and 18.5% of
the West German housing stock was destroyed. [Another source](http://www.ecineq.org/wp-content/uploads/papers_EcineqLSE/EcineqLSE-69.pdf) puts
the estimate at 20% for West Germany. Since West Germany was more
populous than East Germany, the average for the whole country ought to
have been 15-20%.

The map is from 1947 and presumably summarizes building surveys across
Germany. Thus, there is a methodological difference between it and
estimates of Gaza's destruction which are primarily based on satellite
images. For example, a building inspection may reveal that a building
that appears to only have superficial damage has suffered structural
damage and needs to be razed.

According to [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2024/jan/08/the-numbers-that-reveal-the-extent-of-the-destruction-in-gaza) from January 2024:

> Analysis of satellite data cited by the Associated Press suggests
> that about two-thirds of all structures in the north of Gaza have
> been destroyed, and about a quarter in the southern Khan Younis
> area. Across the whole territory, about 33% of buildings have been
> destroyed.

According to [The Wall Street Journal](https://www.wsj.com/world/middle-east/gaza-destruction-bombing-israel-aa528542) from December 2023:

> Nearly 70% of Gaza’s 439,000 homes and about half of its buildings
> have been damaged or destroyed.

According to [NPR](https://www.npr.org/2024/01/14/1224674017/100-days-of-war-23-000-killed-in-gaza-with-over-60-of-homes-destroyed) from January 2024: "More than 60% of all homes
in Gaza have been destroyed" According to [The Times of Israel](https://www.timesofisrael.com/world-bank-report-finds-45-of-residential-buildings-in-gaza-ruined-beyond-repair/)
from January 2024 which cites a World Bank report:

> Some 45 percent of residential buildings in the Gaza Strip have been
> destroyed since war erupted between Israel and Hamas on October 7,
> [...] According to data collected by the international body, over
> 60% of residential buildings in the Gaza Strip, or 132,590
> structures, have been damaged amid the war

According to these figures, the destruction of Gaza is more
total than the destruction of Germany during the war.

One can also compare the destruction to some major German cities that
were hit hard during the war. For example, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombing_of_Berlin_in_World_War_II)
in Berlin "[h]alf of all houses were damaged and around a third
uninhabitable". It also says that 40% of the population fled the city,
which is less than in Gaza where [over 80% has fled](https://news.un.org/en/story/2023/12/1144387).

The Wikipedia page [Strategic bombing during World War II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_bombing_during_World_War_II) cites
"RAF estimates" that claim that the German cities with a population of
500,000 or more that suffered the most damage was; Hamburg (75%),
Düsseldorf (64%), Cologne (61%), Dresden (59%), and Dortmund
(54%). However, the given source for these figures doesn't work so
it's difficult to say how reliable they are or how they were computed
(locating the original source is difficult due to citogenesis).

Comment: The problem with comparing the *overall* average across all of Germany is that it isn't a good comparison to the crowded small area of Gaza. And the Allies didn't target all of Germany, they focussed on specific places (some of industrial, propaganda or military importance). Germany also had about 40 times more people. A better comparison might be specific German cities of similar population to Gaza.

Comment: Also, when the allies targeted the population (ie sites that had no specific military or industrial significance, which was British policy for much of the air war) they did tend to level extreme levels of destruction in a small amount of time.

Comment: @matt_black, German cities of similar population to Gaza?  That's easy: Berlin (50% destroyed per the map, 33% per RAF), Hamburg (50%/75%), and Munich (40%/42%).  Comparable to Gaza, and the fighting in Gaza is still going on.

Comment: @mark In 1943 RAF/USAF operation Gomorrah targeted Hamburg (population >1m) and killed 30-50k people injuring 10 times that, destroyed >50% of the housing all in less than two weeks. Civilian deaths were the policy, not just an accidental overspill from military targets.

Comment: Why compare Gaza with the German city that was hit the hardest (Hamburg)? To make that comparison you'd have to compare it with the Gaza city that was hit the hardest (Beit Hanoun - reduced to rubble). As I understood the question and Josep Borrell's quote, it is about the German national average.

Comment: @StandwithGaza, from a geographic point, Gaza Strip is about 350 square kilometers of continuous urban fabric.  Different pieces may have different names, but it's effectively all one city.